# spring boot AmqpAppender with log4j2

Tags: java, spring, log4j2, spring-amqp

I have a simple Spring Boot application (created in STS as 'starter project'). I'm using log4j2 for logging & want to use the (new org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.6.0.RELEASE) AmqpAppender (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j2.AmqpAppender) to send log messages to a RabbitMQ exchange. Here's the pom file: [pom.xml](https://gist.github.com/maspen/3700e029f0d867401273a3f834efa15d) Here's the xml configuration file: [log4j.xml](https://gist.github.com/maspen/3b02e96fd6082bcfb719be4283eb4dcc)

No matter what i try, I'm not seeing any messages in the exchange; i see them in the console only.

I was successful in using log4j (1) with an older version of org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:1.5.6 AmqpAppender (org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.log4j.AmqpAppender) in a Spring Boot application; i can see the messages in the exchange & have a simple receiver that prints them out in another application. Here's the [log4j.properties](https://gist.github.com/maspen/68bce17e876267af19d4e45d01bef0a0) file.

I'm stuck & cannot find any pertinent examples online.

Please provide a working example including pom file.

Answer (score 0):

Please, find this [Pull Request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp-samples/pull/13), which eventually will move into the main repo for Spring Amqp Samples.

Not sure where is your problem, but at least that working application helps you to play with that Log4J approach.

Comment: Artem thank you for setting this up. i created a new project per you files. unfortunately, when i run the Boot application, i get this message in the console: `ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...` i looked at the dependency graph & log4j-core is already included via spring-boot-starter-log4j2 so no idea what is happening. added this dependency explicitly & still am getting the same error

Comment: Not sure what's going on either. Would be better if you share your Boot application the same way I did: somewhere in GitHub.

Comment: it literally what you provided. here's the [github link](https://github.com/maspen/log4j2-amqp)

Comment: No-op. I downloaded your project and run it like `mvn spring-boot:run`. Everything works perfect! I see logs in console and observe some activity in the `exchange="log4j2_exchange"` via RabbitMQ web manager. Don't want to offend you but looks like you are mocking me ;-)

Comment: How do you run it? Have you tried my `mvn spring-boot:run` command on the matter from the root of the project?

Comment: i deleted .m2/repository and then ran `mvn spring-boot:run` after the dependencies downloaded, the app started fine & am seeing messages in the console as well as in the web manager. thank you!

Comment: He-he! That's why I prefer Gradle :-). Glad to see that you are already on a good path. So, let's "Accept" my answer and go to work!